# Everything I draw on canvas using Fabric is in offset

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When I draw on the canvas using Fabric lib everything is in offset.
Here is the code:

```
Fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 100, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 10, top: 10});
var line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 100, 100], {stroke: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 3, selectable: false});

Fcanvas.add(circle, triangle,line);
Fcanvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, 20, 530, 20], {stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 3, selectable: false}));
```

and on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/h4unywm3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a bug in the version of fabric.js you are using? If you run the Fiddle against 1.2.0 everything seems as expected. Alternatively it is possible the API has changed between the versions somehow and you'll need to add some code to match the earlier behavior.

Comment: thanks, you are totally write. I just started working with Fabric and it seems strange that such a bug exist in an official version. do you know where can I find and download version 1.2.0 ? I would also like to test it with the latest version 1.4.12 but it download the full library and I do not know how to build the min file

Comment: Just tested it with the latest version 1.4.12 and it's working fine

Comment: Ok. Great to hear 1.4.12 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the JSFIDDLE with the latest fabric version and everything works as expected.

To build the latest version by yourself download the zip from github, download nodejs.exe from nodejs website.

Then place nodejs in the fabric folder you just downloaded and run: 
node build.js modules=ALL  ( optionally add ) exclude=json,cufon,gestures